# Is there a way to print a commands stdout/stderr only after a given 'timeout'?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, timeout

Imagine a command which usually takes less than a second to complete an in this case you don't want to get bothered with verbose output, but sometimes it takes longer and in that case you want to have some visual status to be printed.

E.g. one thing I do regularly is combining `docker build` with `docker run`:

```
docker build -t foo ...   # usually terminates in < 1s, but sometimes takes minutes
docker run ... foo ...
```

other examples might involve `cp` or any other command which output is only interesting when running for longer than a couple of seconds.

What you can do if you're not interested in verbose output at all is just piping it to `/dev/null`, more sophisticated approaches record the output and only print it if somethings going wrong.

But is there built-into-bash way to say: run command XY and show output only on error or if the command is running for more than `$TIMEOUT` seconds?

like

```
paranoid-quieten 2 docker build -t foo ...
```

or maybe

```
docker build -t foo ... | paranoid-quieten 2
```

I knew how to make a python script out of this (would be somehow tricky though) but how do you do it?

Comment: "is there built-into-bash way to say: run command XY and show output only on error or if the command is running for more than `$TIMEOUT` seconds?" -- Probably not. When Bash runs a program, it does not relay its output to the terminal or whatever. The program inherits file descriptors and/or opens files by itself, then it reads and/or writes directly. Bash only waits for SIGCHLD. I think it is possible to do what you want (and maybe this could involve some Bash builtins), but it's not we're almost there because "Bash is a relay anyway". Bash is not a relay.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324213/pass-through-pipe-with-timeout